# Is there any way to squash all the common commits, which is shared across all branches, in one go?

Tags: git

Here is a representation of my current working git tree

```
* 39a28d2 (origin/view-creation, view-creation) Completed views ...
* 22e9359 (origin/menu-creation, menu-creation) Created menus ...
| * ef22d1d (origin/domain-creation, domain-creation) updated selects.xml ...
|/  
* 93cef7a Updated domains ...
* b732d08 (origin/project-creation, project-creation) Created modules: contact & sales ...
* 72defa9 (origin/main, main) Basic working project
* b55de24 Initial commit : Added .gitignore
* f7e61eb Initial commit
```

Now i want to squash 3 commits from the very bottom, into one.
I can and did interactive rebasing and squashed them in one, but have to do multiple times as all the branch, naturally, share the same commit history.

Even if it try rebasing the branches, it's still lot of work and potential merge conflicts.

Is there any way to squash it once, and then push the changes onto all the branches?

Comment: Merge conflicts are not avoidable in this case. You need to pick one of them as the new base and rebase/cherry-pick the commits of the other branches onto the new base. Another option is to pick one of their heads as the target branch and merge the other heads.

Comment: since you want to keep the existing content of commist as they are, you can do a `git replace + git filter-repo` trick. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72536874/86072  (<- shameless self plug) note: it is recommended to run `git filter-repo --force` on a fresh clone, otherwise you will lose your reflog. You can then push the rewritten history and update other clones based on that.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it for one of thee branches and then rebase the other, which should be a pretty straight forward thing to do.... I could even tip you to use a script I used *if you do not mess with the `trees`*.

https://github.com/eantoranz/git-replay

Say you squashed on `view-creation` and got this:

```
* 39a28d2' (origin/view-creation, view-creation) Completed views ...
* 22e9359' Created menus ...
* xxxxxx Squash up to 93cef7a
* f7e61eb Initial commit
```

Then, a branch like `domain-creation` could be "rebased" like this (assuming, again, that `xxxxxx` and `93cef7a` have the same `tree`):

```
./git-replay xxxxxx 93cef7a domain-creation
```

Just in case, the *standard* way would be:

```
git rebase --onto xxxxxx 93cef7a domain-creation
```

`menu-creation` is a special case because it is an ancestor to `view-creation` so, if you did not use `--update-refs` when rebasing, you could do:

```
git branch -f menu-creation view-creation~
```